# Python; Using NGram sentiment analysis - cannot get top 5 words

Tags: python, n-gram

I set up my CountVectorizer as follows;

```
cv = CountVectorizer(binary=True)
X = cv.fit_transform(train_text)
X_test = cv.transform(test_text)
```

And when I use SVM I can print off the top 5 words in my Sentiment Analysis;

```
final_svm  = LinearSVC(C=best_c)
final_svm.fit(X, target)
final_accuracy = final_svm.predict(X_test)
final_accuracy_score = accuracy_score(target_test, final_accuracy)
print ("Final SVM Accuracy: %s" % final_accuracy_score)
Report_Matricies.accuracy(target_test, final_accuracy)
feature_names = zip(cv.get_feature_names(), final_model.coef_[0])
feature_to_coef = {
    word: coef for word, coef in feature_names
}
itemz = feature_to_coef.items()
list_positive = sorted(
    itemz, 
    key=lambda x: x[1], 
    reverse=True)[:number_we_are_interested_in]
```

So that works. But when I try similar code for NGram, I get random words instead;

```
   ngram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=True, ngram_range=(1, no_of_words))
    X = ngram_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_text)
    X_test = ngram_vectorizer.transform(test_text)
    best_c = Logistic_Regression.get_best_hyperparameter(X_train, y_train, y_val, X_val)
    final_ngram = LogisticRegression(C=best_c)
    final_ngram.fit(X, target)
    final_accuracy = final_ngram.predict(X_test)
    final_accuracy_score = accuracy_score(target_test, final_accuracy)
    print ("Final NGram Accuracy: %s" % final_accuracy_score)
    Report_Matricies.accuracy(target_test, final_accuracy)
    feature_names = zip(cv.get_feature_names(), final_ngram.coef_[0])
    feature_to_coef = {
        word: coef for word, coef in feature_names
    }
    itemz = feature_to_coef.items()
    list_positive = sorted(
        itemz, 
        key=lambda x: x[1], 
        reverse=True)
```

The accuracy ratings between my NGram analysis and SVM are similar, so the code I am using for NGramm does not seem to be correct for extracting the kind of words I want, that is they are random words rather than positive words. What code should I be using instead?
Similar code can be found on this reference, but the example in part 2 does not print the top 5 words for NGram.
https://towardsdatascience.com/sentiment-analysis-with-python-part-1-5ce197074184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered by [aberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6107054/aberger), maybe you should replace :

- "feature_names = zip(**cv**.get_feature_names(), final_ngram.coef_[0])"
  by
- "feature_names = zip(**ngram_vectorizer**.get_feature_names(), final_ngram.coef_[0])"

---

**A couple of additional considerations**

In NLP, NGrams is the fact of considering N contiguous words as a single word. It will be used to "tokenize" your text corpus, in order to make this corpus usable by a machine algorithm, but it doesn't have to do with the algorithm itself.

SVM and Logistic regression are two distinct algorithm mostly used for classification (logistic regression is a regression used to separate classes, it's the way we use it that makes this regression a classification algorithm).

I tried to illustrate this with meaningless data (you can replace with yours) so that you can directly run this code and observe results.

As you can see, using NGrams will give almost the same top words, except a bigram and a trigram in my own run :

- Logistic regression without NGrams : [('the', 0.22492305532420143), ('boxing', 0.22366726197682427), ('jump', 0.22366726197682427), ('wizards', 0.22366726197682427), ('five', 0.21116962061694416)]
- Logistic regression with NGrams : [('the', 0.1549468448457053), ('five', 0.15263348614045338), ('boxing', 0.12657434061922093), ('boxing wizards', 0.12657434061922093), ('boxing wizards jump', 0.12657434061922093)]
- Logistic regression with NGrams but sorting only unigrams : [('the', 0.1549468448457053), ('five', 0.15263348614045338), ('boxing', 0.12657434061922093), ('jump', 0.12657434061922093), ('wizards', 0.12657434061922093)] <- Give almost the same thing than "Logistic regression without NGrams" (not exactly the same as the model has learned with different tokens, i.e. the additional NGrams here)

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

text_train = ["The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog",
        "Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs",
        "How quickly daft jumping zebras vex",
        "The five boxing wizards jump quickly",
        "the fox of my friend it the most lazy one I have seen in the past five years"]

text_test = ["just for a test"]

target_train = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

target_test = [1]

#######################################################################
##       OBSERVING TOKENIZATION OF DATA WITH AND WITOUT NGRAMS       ##
#######################################################################

## WITHOUT NGRAMS

cv = CountVectorizer()
count_vector = cv.fit_transform(text_train)
#Display the dictionary pairing each single word and it's position in the
#"vectorized" version of our text corpus, without any count.
print("")
print(cv.vocabulary_)
print("")
print("")
print(dict(zip(cv.get_feature_names(), count_vector.toarray().sum(axis=0))))

##  WITH NGRAMS

#Now let's also add as meaningfull entities all pair and all trios of words
#using NGrams
cv = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3))
count_vector = cv.fit_transform(text_train)
#Observe that now, "jump quickly" and "large fawn jumped" for instance are 
#considered as sort of meaningful unique "words" composed of several unique
#words.
print("")
print("")
print(cv.vocabulary_)
print("")
print("")
#List of all words and counts their occurences
print(dict(zip(cv.get_feature_names(), count_vector.toarray().sum(axis=0))))

#######################################################################
##                    YOUR ATTEMPT WITH LINEARSVC                    ##
#######################################################################
cv1 = CountVectorizer(binary=True)
count_vector_train = cv1.fit_transform(text_train)
count_vector_test = cv1.transform(text_test)

final_svm  = LinearSVC(C=1.0)
final_svm.fit(count_vector_train, target_train)
final_accuracy = final_svm.predict(count_vector_test)
final_accuracy_score = accuracy_score(target_test, final_accuracy)
print("")
print("")
print ("Final SVM without NGrams Accuracy: %s" % final_accuracy_score)
feature_names = zip(cv1.get_feature_names(), final_svm.coef_[0])
feature_to_coef = {
    word: coef for word, coef in feature_names
}
itemz = feature_to_coef.items()
list_positive = sorted(
    itemz, 
    key=lambda x: x[1], 
    reverse=True)[:5] #Here you can choose the top 5
print("")
print("SVM without NGrams")
print(list_positive)

#######################################################################
##              YOUR ATTEMPT WITH LOGISTIC REGRESSION                ##
#######################################################################
cv2 = CountVectorizer(binary=True)
count_vector_train = cv2.fit_transform(text_train)
count_vector_test = cv2.transform(text_test)

final_lr  = LogisticRegression(C=1.0)
final_lr.fit(count_vector_train, target_train)
final_accuracy = final_lr.predict(count_vector_test)
final_accuracy_score = accuracy_score(target_test, final_accuracy)
print("")
print("")
print ("Final Logistic regression without NGrams Accuracy: %s" % final_accuracy_score)
feature_names = zip(cv2.get_feature_names(), final_lr.coef_[0])
feature_to_coef = {
    word: coef for word, coef in feature_names
}
itemz = feature_to_coef.items()
list_positive = sorted(
    itemz, 
    key=lambda x: x[1], 
    reverse=True)[:5] #Here you can choose the top 5
print("")
print("Logistic regression without NGrams")
print(list_positive)

#######################################################################
##         YOUR ATTEMPT WITH LOGISTIC REGRESSION AND NGRAMS          ##
#######################################################################
cv3 = CountVectorizer(binary=True, ngram_range=(1,3))
count_vector_train = cv3.fit_transform(text_train)
count_vector_test = cv3.transform(text_test)

final_lr  = LogisticRegression(C=1.0)
final_lr.fit(count_vector_train, target_train)
final_accuracy = final_lr.predict(count_vector_test)
final_accuracy_score = accuracy_score(target_test, final_accuracy)
print("")
print("")
print ("Final Logistic regression with NGrams Accuracy: %s" % final_accuracy_score)
feature_names = zip(cv3.get_feature_names(), final_lr.coef_[0])
feature_to_coef = {
    word: coef for word, coef in feature_names
}
itemz = feature_to_coef.items()
list_positive = sorted(
    itemz, 
    key=lambda x: x[1], 
    reverse=True)[:5] #Here you can choose the top 5
print("")
print("Logistic regression with NGrams")
print(list_positive)

#######################################################################
##         YOUR ATTEMPT WITH LOGISTIC REGRESSION AND NGRAMS          ##
##                BUT EXTRACTS ONLY REAL UNIQUE WORDS                ##
#######################################################################
cv4 = CountVectorizer(binary=True, ngram_range=(1,3))
count_vector_train = cv4.fit_transform(text_train)
count_vector_test = cv4.transform(text_test)

final_lr  = LogisticRegression(C=1.0)
final_lr.fit(count_vector_train, target_train)
final_accuracy = final_lr.predict(count_vector_test)
final_accuracy_score = accuracy_score(target_test, final_accuracy)
print("")
print("")
print ("Final Logistic regression with NGrams Accuracy: %s" % final_accuracy_score)
feature_names = zip(cv4.get_feature_names(), final_lr.coef_[0])
feature_names_unigrams = [(a, b) for a, b in feature_names if len(a.split()) < 2]
feature_to_coef = {
    word: coef for word, coef in feature_names_unigrams
}
itemz = feature_to_coef.items()

list_positive = sorted(
    itemz,
    key=lambda x: x[1], 
    reverse=True)[:5] #Here you can choose the top 5
print("")
print("Logistic regression with NGrams but only getting unigrams")
print(list_positive)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did a little too much copy/paste when you implemented your Logistic Regression model trained on ngrams. When you get `feature_names` from this model you're using the binary CountVectorizer, `cv`, instead of `ngram_vectorizer`. I think you need to change the line

`feature_names = zip(cv.get_feature_names(), final_ngram.coef_[0])`

to

`feature_names = zip(ngram_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), final_ngram.coef_[0])`